# For loop is going again and again for the same values

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am not sure what is going wrong. But the system is printing the same values again and again, where it should echo the value only once where it is matching student_id in the delivery table. The full code I have edited as requested. This is not executing the query but able display the Table headings.

The code is :

```
    <?php $min = $this->db->get_where('academic_settings' , array('type' =>'minium_mark'))->row()->description;?>
<?php $running_year = $this->db->get_where('settings' , array('type' => 'running_year'))->row()->description; ?>

<div class="content-w">
      <div class="conty">
          <?php include 'fancy.php';?>
          <div class="header-spacer"></div>
     <div class="content-i">
    <div class="content-box">
            <div class="row">   

                                                                                          
                                                    <div class="table-responsive">
                                                    <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-lightfont">
<tbody>

 
                <tr>
                    <td style="color:black !important; text-transform:uppercase; text-align:center;">
                    <?php echo get_phrase('Subject_Name');?>&nbsp;:&nbsp;
                        <span><?php echo $row['name'];?></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                                <table class="table table-padded">
                                <thead style="background-color:#90be2e; color:white;">
                                    <tr style="padding-bottom:4px; padding-top:4px;">
                                <th style="color:white;"><?php echo get_phrase('Publish Date');?></th>
                                <th style="color:white;"><?php echo get_phrase('Assignment');?></th>
                                <th style="color:white;"><?php echo get_phrase('Faculty');?></th>
                                <th style="color:white;"><?php echo get_phrase('Last Date');?></th>
                                <th style="color:white;"><?php echo get_phrase('Submitted On');?></th>
                                <th style="color:white;"><?php echo get_phrase('Marks');?></th>
                                <th style="color:white;"><?php echo get_phrase('Feedback');?></th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            
<?php 
     $uploader_id_student = $this->db->get_where('student', array('student_id' => $this->session->userdata('login_user_id')))->row()->student_id;
     $invoices = $this->db->get_where('deliveries', array('student_id' => $uploader_id_student))->result_array(); 
                
                foreach($invoices as $row2): 
 ?> 
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $this->db->get_where('homework' , array('homework_code'=>$row2['homework_code']))->row()->upload_date;?> 
                        </td> 
                        <td>
                            <?php 
                                $get_homework_data = $this->db->get_where('homework' , array('homework_code'=>$row2['homework_code']))->row();
                                echo wordwrap($get_homework_data->title,15,"<br>\n");
                               ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php 
                                echo $this->db->get_where('teacher' , array('teacher_id'=>$get_homework_data->uploader_id))->row()->first_name;
                            ?>&nbsp; 
                            <?php 
                                echo $this->db->get_where('teacher' , array('teacher_id'=>$get_homework_data->uploader_id))->row()->last_name;
                             ?>                         
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php 
                                $sampleDate1 = $this->db->get_where('homework' , array('homework_code'=>$row2['homework_code']))->row()->date_end;
                                $convertDate1 = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($sampleDate1));
                                echo $convertDate1;

                            ?>                          
                         </td>
                         <td>
                            <?php
                                $sampleDate = $row2['date'];
                                $convertDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($sampleDate));
                                echo $convertDate;
                            ?>
                        </td> 
                        <td style="text-align:center;">
                            <?php echo $row2['mark'];?>
                        </td> 
                        <td>
                            <?php echo wordwrap($row2['teacher_comment'],25,"<br>\n");?>
                        </td> 

                  </tr>
                            
            <?php endforeach;?>
                                                        
    <!--<?php endforeach;?> -->
                            </tbody>
                            </table>
                </td>
                        
            </tr>               
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>

                                         </div>
                                       
                                            </div>
                                            </div>
                                                </div>  
                                            </div>
                                            
                                               
        </div>
```

attached is screenshot of table Deliveries is there [Deliveries Picture Download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PoY7.png)

Comment: are you using codeigniter, slim or what specific framework? which version? can you please edit your code in order to include the whole foreach statement?

Comment: Not an answer to your issue, but you already have the student id from the session. The first line can just be `$uploader_student_id = $this->session->userdata('login_user_id')`.
Also you're doing an unnecessary amount of queries. You can do `$teacher = $this->db->get_where(...)->row()` and then `echo $teacher->first_name` and `echo $teacher->last_name`. (Same for homework.)

Comment: @lucasreta - They have tagged it with codeigniter so we can assume that's what they're using.

Comment: thank you guys for the comments, I am not an expert in coding. Just trying my hands on generating a report. Had learned HTML and java in 2000. I really need this to work.

Comment: @SheetalSharma can you please post the whole code?

Comment: @lucasreta posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code updated to fix the performance issues mentioned by Arnold Daniels.

```php
<?php
$uploader_id_student = $this->session->userdata('login_user_id');
$invoices = $this->db->get_where('deliveries', array('student_id' => $uploader_id_student))->result_array(); 
foreach($invoices as $row2) {
  $get_homework_data = $this->db->get_where('homework' , array('homework_code'=>$row2['homework_code']))->row();
  $teacher = $this->db->get_where('teacher' , array('teacher_id'=>$get_homework_data->uploader_id))->row();
?>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <?= $get_homework_data->upload_date ?> 
    </td> 
    <td>
      <?= wordwrap($get_homework_data->title,25,"<br>\n") ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?= $teacher->first_name . ' ' . $teacher->last_name ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

It appears to be working fine as far as I could test it. Is there anything missing from the snippet you posted that could help reproduce your issue?

#### Edit:

So the complete code would be:

```php
<?php
$min = $this->db->get_where('academic_settings' , array('type' =>'minium_mark'))->row()->description;
$running_year = $this->db->get_where('settings', array('type' => 'running_year'))->row()->description;
?>
<div class="content-w">
  <div class="conty">
    <?php include 'fancy.php'; ?>
    <div class="header-spacer"></div>
    <div class="content-i">
      <div class="content-box">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-lightfont">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td style="color:black !important; text-transform:uppercase; text-align:center;">
                    <?php echo get_phrase('Subject_Name'); ?>&nbsp;:&nbsp;
                    <span><?php echo $row['name']; ?></span>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <table class="table table-padded">
                      <thead style="background-color:#90be2e; color:white;">
                        <tr style="padding-bottom:4px; padding-top:4px;">
                          <th style="color:white;"><?php echo get_phrase('Publish Date'); ?></th>
                          <th style="color:white;"><?php echo get_phrase('Assignment'); ?></th>
                          <th style="color:white;"><?php echo get_phrase('Faculty'); ?></th>
                          <th style="color:white;"><?php echo get_phrase('Last Date'); ?></th>
                          <th style="color:white;"><?php echo get_phrase('Submitted On'); ?></th>
                          <th style="color:white;"><?php echo get_phrase('Marks'); ?></th>
                          <th style="color:white;"><?php echo get_phrase('Feedback'); ?></th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <?php
                        $uploader_id_student = $this->db->get_where('student', array('student_id' => $this->session->userdata('login_user_id')))->row()->student_id;
                        $invoices = $this->db->get_where('deliveries', array('student_id' => $uploader_id_student))->result_array();
                        foreach ($invoices as $row2) :
                          $homework_data = $this->db->get_where('homework', array('homework_code' => $row2['homework_code']))->row();
                          $teacher = $this->db->get_where('teacher', array('teacher_id' => $get_homework_data->uploader_id))->row();
                        ?>
                          <tr>
                            <td>
                              <?php echo $homework_data->title->upload_date; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                              <?php
                              echo wordwrap($homework_data->title, 15, "<br>\n");
                              ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                              <?php
                              echo $teacher->first_name;
                              ?>&nbsp;
                              <?php
                              echo $teacher->last_name;
                              ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                              <?php
                              $sampleDate1 = $homework_data->date_end;
                              $convertDate1 = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($sampleDate1));
                              echo $convertDate1;
                              ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                              <?php
                              $sampleDate = $row2['date'];
                              $convertDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($sampleDate));
                              echo $convertDate;
                              ?>
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align:center;">
                              <?php echo $row2['mark']; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                              <?php echo wordwrap($row2['teacher_comment'], 25, "<br>\n"); ?>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would need to see the contents of the included file "fancy.php" to be sure. There was an extra `endforeach` statement, but I'm guessing that it came from somewhere beyond the scope of the snippet you updated. I would need to see the whole content of the file and the content of the included script in order to determine the true nature of the error.

Comment: This page should auto execute the Query, when loads. I have uploaded the whole code in the main.

Comment: @SheetalSharma updated my answer, please read and edit the post accordingly if the current fix doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Yes this worked. Dont know where the endforeach I missed. This is exactly I wanted. Cheers to you @lucasreta

Comment: @SheetalSharma glad to hear it worked! If so, please accept the answer as correct. The extra foreach was "commented" in your original snipper, like so: `<!--<?php endforeach;?> -->`, but the html comment has no impact on the php opening and closing tags.

Answer (score 0):

`<!--<?php endforeach;?> -->`

Remove this Line